# Create folder Enterprise Connect

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm working on Enterprise connect and I would like to create a folder in path(7) in the next link:

```
myFolder=myNameSpace.Folders("LiveLink").Folders("Livelink_ACL").Folders("Company").Folders(path(1)).Folders(path(2)).
Folders(path(3)).Folders(path(4)).Folders(path(5)).Folders(path(6)).Folders(path(7))
```

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simply use following to create a new folder:

```
myFolder.Folders.Add("FolderName")
```

Where `myFolder` hold the reference of the parent folder.

Comment: myFolder.Add("FolderName") don't run. I have error 438 "object doesn't support this property or method. Thank you

Comment: It must be myFolder.Folders.Add("FolderName")

Comment: Corrected! Thanks Brodyeva for your eagle eye.